Facing an error while creating and merge a gitlab mr using python script
I'm trying to create and merge a gitlab mr using python script, the mr was created without any error, but I got an error message while trying to merge it "422, {"message":"Branch cannot be merged"}", how can i get more details about the error? Is there any issue with my script? Thanks
The functions used to create and merge it:
def create_merge_request(token, project_id, source_branch, target_branch, title, description):
    """Créer une Merge Request sur GitLab."""
    url = f"{GITLAB_HOST_HTTPS}/api/v4/projects/{project_id}/merge_requests"
    headers = {"PRIVATE-TOKEN": token}
    data = {
        "source_branch": source_branch,
        "target_branch": target_branch,
        "title": title,
        "description": description,
        "merge_when_pipeline_succeeds": False,  # Désactiver la fusion conditionnelle
        "remove_source_branch": True,   # Supprimer la branche source après fusion
        "squash": True                        # Ne pas écraser les commits
    }

    response = requests.post(url, headers=headers, json=data)

    if response.status_code == 201:
        mr_data = response.json()
        print(f"Merge Request créée avec succès : {mr_data.get('web_url')}")
        return mr_data  # Retourne les détails de la MR
    else:
        print(f"Erreur lors de la création de la Merge Request : {response.json()}")
        return None

def merge_mr(token, project_id, merge_request_iid):
    """Fusionner une Merge Request via l'API GitLab."""
    url = f"{GITLAB_HOST_HTTPS}/api/v4/projects/{project_id}/merge_requests/{merge_request_iid}/merge"
    headers = {"PRIVATE-TOKEN": token}

    print(f"URL utilisée pour le merge : {url}")
    response = requests.put(url, headers=headers) #, json=data

    if response.status_code == 200:
        print("Merge Request mergée avec succès.")
        return response.json()
    elif response.status_code == 405:
        print("Erreur 405 : Méthode non autorisée. Vérifiez la méthode HTTP (PUT).")
    else:
        print(f"Erreur lors de la Merge : {response.status_code}, {response.text}")
    return None
def create_and_merge_mr(token, project_id, source_branch, target_branch, title, description):
    """Créer une MR et la merger immédiatement si possible."""
    # Étape 1 : Créer la MR
    mr_data = create_merge_request(token, project_id, source_branch, target_branch, title, description)
    if not mr_data:
        print("Échec de la création de la Merge Request.")
        return
    
    # Étape 2 : Récupérer l'ID interne de la MR (iid)
    merge_request_iid = mr_data.get('iid')
    if not merge_request_iid:
        print("Impossible de récupérer l'ID interne de la Merge Request.")
        return
    
    # Étape 3 : Fusionner la MR
    merge_result = merge_mr(token, project_id, merge_request_iid)
    if merge_result:
        print("MR mergée avec succès.")
    else:
        print("Échec de la merge de la MR.")

def main():
    parser = ArgumentParser()
    parser.add_argument("--client_group_name", help="Nom du groupe client à filtrer", default=None)
    parser.add_argument("--yaml_file", help="Chemin du fichier YAML pour les topics", default="nature-topics.yaml")
    parser.add_argument("--gitlab_token", help="GitLab token for authentication", required=True)
    parser.add_argument("--nature", help="Nature of the environment (e.g., dev, qa)", required=True)
    args = parser.parse_args()


    #1.
    #2.
    #3.
    #4.



    # 9. merge la MR
    # git_merge_branches(local_repo_path, new_branch, branch)
    create_and_merge_mr(
        args.gitlab_token, 
        project_id, 
        new_branch, 
        branch, 
        "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx", 
        "yyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyy" 
    )

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()

